# Merging Two Array of Objects in angular 6

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I have two arrays something like this.

```
array1 = [{name:'arjun', place:'mysore'},{name:'kanka', place:'bangalore'}];
array2 = [{name: 'arjun', degree:'BE'},{name:'kanka', degree:'MCA'}]
```

The result Should be Something like this.

```
array3 = [{name: 'arjun', place:'mysore', degree:'BE'}, {name:'kanka',place:'bangalore',degree:'MCA'}];
```

The above result Array doesn't have duplicate values now. Can anyone help please?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do arrays have the same length? Same order?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you need to merge arrays by `index` and are of `same length`.

```js
let array1 = [{name:'arjun', place:'mysore'},{name:'kanka', place:'bangalore'}];
let array2 = [{name: 'arjun', degree:'BE'},{name:'kanka', degree:'MCA'}]

let array3 = array1.map((o,i) => ({...o, ...array2[i]}));
console.log(array3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a `Array.map()` and `Object.assign()`

```js
array1 = [{name:'arjun', place:'mysore'},{name:'kanka', place:'bangalore'}];
array2 = [{name: 'arjun', degree:'BE'},{name:'kanka', degree:'MCA'}];

let result = array1.map((a)=>{
 let obj2 = array2.find((b)=> a.name === b.name);
 if(obj2)
  Object.assign(a,obj2);
 return a;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do something like this perhaps:

```js
array1 = [{name:'arjun', place:'mysore'},{name:'kanka', place:'bangalore'}];
array2 = [{name: 'arjun', degree:'BE'},{name:'kanka', degree:'MCA'}]

var resultArray = array1.reduce((arr, e) => {
  arr.push(Object.assign({}, e, array2.find(a => a.name == e.name)))
  return arr;
}, [])


console.log(resultArray);
```

**NOTE**: It will also work if those arrays are of different length.

Answer (score 1):

use the `foreach` like this

```js
let array1 = [{name:'arjun', place:'mysore'},{name:'kanka', place:'bangalore'}];
let array2 = [{name: 'arjun', degree:'BE'},{name:'kanka', degree:'MCA'}]


let array3 = [];

array1.forEach((item, index) => {
    array3.push(item)
    let degree = array2.find(e => e.name === item.name)
    if(degree){
      array3[index].degree = degree.degree
    }
})

console.log(array3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If both arrays are of the same length then this solution will work.

```
array1 = [{name:'arjun', place:'mysore'},{name:'kanka', place:'bangalore'}];
array2 = [{name: 'arjun', degree:'BE'},{name:'kanka', degree:'MCA'}]

const array3 = [];
for(let i=0; i < array1.length; i++){
    array3.push(Object.assign(array1[i], array2[i]));
}
console.log(array3);
```

Working [JSBin here](https://jsbin.com/helijubopi/edit?js,console).

Look here also: [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

You can make an aggregation of properties by the `name` with `reduce` and `map` out the aggregated data to an array:

```
const array1 = [{name:'arjun', place:'mysore'},{name:'kanka', place:'bangalore'}];
const array2 = [{name: 'arjun', degree:'BE'},{name:'kanka', degree:'MCA'}];

const objData = [...array1, ...array2].reduce((all, { name, place, degree }) => {

    if (!all.hasOwnProperty(name)) all[name] = { name };
    if (place) all[name].place = place;
    if (degree) all[name].degree = degree;

    return all;

}, {});

const result = Object.keys(objData).map(k => objData[k]);

console.log(result);
```