# Javascript how to join two arrays having same property value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-map

How do I join arrays with the same property value? I cannot map it because it has different indexes.

```
var array1 = [
        {'label':"label1",'position':0},
        {'label':"label3",'position':2},
        {'label':"label2",'position':1},
    ];

var array2 = [
        {'label':"label1",'value':"TEXT"},
        {'label':"label2",'value':"SELECT"}
     ];
```

expected output:

```
var array3 = [
        {'label':"label1",'value':"TEXT",'position':0},
        {'label':"label2",'value':"SELECT", 'position':1}
     ];
```

This is what I did, I cannot make it work,

```
var arr3 = arr1.map(function(v, i) {
        return {
            "label": v.label,
            "position": v.position,
            "value": arr2[?].value
        }
   });
```

Comment: Did you mean to leave out label3?, if so you might want to say you want a union too.

Comment: yes I want to remove the label3 and just display 2 as the output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a union of two arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629817/getting-a-union-of-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282996/merging-two-array-of-objects-in-angular-6/51283263#51283263

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do something like this perhaps:

```js
var array1 = [
        {'label':"label1",'position':0},
        {'label':"label3",'position':2},
        {'label':"label2",'position':1},
    ];

var array2 = [
        {'label':"label1",'value':"TEXT"},
        {'label':"label2",'value':"SELECT"}
     ];

var array3 = array2.reduce((arr, e) => {
  arr.push(Object.assign({}, e, array1.find(a => a.label == e.label)))
  return arr;
}, [])


console.log(array3);
```

Comment: This depends on `array2` having all its labels matching in `array1`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes. OP can provide a default value in case the value not found. Eg `arr.find() || {default object }`

Comment: I think what @CertainPerformance is meaning is say you changed label2 to say label4 in array2, you will get two results, this violates the union requirement.

Comment: thank you for your help, i didnt know such function exists

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and check the existence for a new object.

```js
var array1 = [{ label: "label1", position: 0 }, { label: "label3", position: 2 }, { label: "label2", position: 1 }],
    array2 = [{ label: "label1", value: "TEXT" }, { label: "label2", value: "SELECT" }],
    map = array1.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.label, o), new Map),
    array3 = array2.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (map.has(o.label)) {
            r.push(Object.assign({}, o, map.get(o.label)));
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(array3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know in advance which array(s) will have their labels be a subset of the other (if any), here's a method that allows for either `array1` or `array2` to have `label`s that the other array lacks. Use `reduce` over `array1`, `find`ing the matching label in `array2` if it exists:

```js
var array1 = [
  {'label':"label1",'position':0},
  {'label':"label3",'position':2},
  {'label':"label2",'position':1},
];
var array2 = [
  {'label':"label1",'value':"TEXT"},
  {'label':"label2",'value':"SELECT"}
];

const output = array1.reduce((a, { label, position }) => {
  const foundValueObj = array2.find(({ label: findLabel }) => findLabel === label);
  if (!foundValueObj) return a;
  const { value } = foundValueObj;
  a.push({ label, value, position });
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the effort, we take an assumption that `array1` will be having all the `labels` that are in `array2`.

Based on that first, create a map for `array2`and with key being `labels`. Post that, filter out `array1` items which have labels existing in the map and then finally merging the objects of the filtered array and its corresponding values in map extracted from `array2`.

```js
var array1 = [{'label':"label1",'position':0},{'label':"label3",'position':2},{'label':"label2",'position':1}];
var array2 = [{'label':"label1",'value':"TEXT"},{'label':"label2",'value':"SELECT"}];
     
let map = array2.reduce((a,{label, ...rest}) => Object.assign(a,{[label]:rest}),{});
let result = array1.filter(({label}) => map[label]).map(o => ({...o, ...map[o.label]}));
console.log(result);
```

Also, in the above snippet, you can improve the performance further by using `Array.reduce` against filter and map functions to retrieve the result.

```js
var array1 = [{'label':"label1",'position':0},{'label':"label3",'position':2},{'label':"label2",'position':1}];
var array2 = [{'label':"label1",'value':"TEXT"},{'label':"label2",'value':"SELECT"}];
     
let map = array2.reduce((a,{label, ...rest}) => Object.assign(a,{[label]:rest}),{});
let result = array1.reduce((a,o) => {
if(map[o.label]) a.push({...o, ...map[o.label]});
return a;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: In Chrome for me run snippet gets ->  `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {",`

Comment: Is this answer supposed to compile?

Comment: @Keith - It does now. A typo changed removed the `,` from `array2`.

Comment: @ArmanCharan - It does now. A typo changed removed the `,` from `array2`.

Answer (score 0):

See [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for more info.

```js
// Input.
const A = [{'label':"label1",'position':0},{'label':"label3",'position':2},{'label':"label2",'position':1}]
const B = [{'label':"label1",'value':"TEXT"},{'label':"label2",'value':"SELECT"}]

// Merge Union.
const mergeUnion = (A, B) => {
  const mapA = new Map(A.map(x => [x.label, x]))
  return B.map(y => ({...mapA.get(y.label), ...y}))
}

// Output + Proof.
const output = mergeUnion(A, B)
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

**Approach**: Concatenate the objects with same `label`, using [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
var array1 = [{'label':"label1",'position':0},{'label':"label3",'position':2},{'label':"label2",'position':1}];
var array2 = [{'label':"label1",'value':"TEXT"},{'label':"label2",'value':"SELECT"}];
var result = [];

array2.forEach(function(value, index){
    result.push(Object.assign({},array1.find(function(v,i){return v.label==value.label}),value));
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not good with javascript,but you could also do this

```
    var array1 = [
    {'label':"label1",'position':0},
    {'label':"label3",'position':2},
    {'label':"label2",'position':1},
];

    var array2 = [
    {'label':"label1",'value':"TEXT"},
    {'label':"label2",'value':"SELECT"}
 ];
     var array3=[];
 for(var i=0;i<array1.length;i++)
    {
        for(var x=0;x<array2.length;x++)
        {       
                console.log(array1[i]['label'] == array2[x]['label']);
                if(array1[i]['label'] == array2[x]['label']){
                array3.push({label:array1[i]['label'],value:array2[x]['value'],position:array1[i]['position']});

                }
        }        
    }
    console.log(array3);
```